# Cat prepend to first line, NOT new line

Tags: text-processing, command-line

So I have kinda just resigned to using nano for this, but I though I would put it out on Unix.Linux to A) Challenge somebody and B) learn how/if It can be done.

I want to prepend a link to an rsa file (command="/sbin/shutdown -h now").

Most of the things I found when google "cat prepend to file" make it so it would end up like this .

```
command="/sbin/shutdown -h now"
ssh-rsa MyRSsAkEyasetcetc
```

**What I need is :**

```
command="/sbin/shutdown -h now" ssh-rsa MySRasKeytsadnasdnasd
```

Aka all one line, prepend to first line.

Comment: `printf '%s ' 'command="/sbin/shutdown -h now"'; cat file`

Comment: That seems easier than it is to cat a new line!, much cleaner. Will have to try it out... Here I was thinking it would be a challenge :P

Comment: Using the approach requires you  to redirect the output; eg `printf .. >newfile ; cat ... >> newfile` or maybe easier to wrap it ; eg `( printf ... ; cat .. ) > newfile`

Comment: I don't find where you're executing the `cat` command. Is that `cat file` where the result is `command="/sbin/shutdown -h now"` or `cat key.pub` where the result is `ssh-rsa MySRasKeytsadnasdnasd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple `sed` command:

```
sed 's!^!command="/sbin/shutdown -h now" !'
```

If the public key is in a file then you can use the `-i` flag to edit the file in place:

```
$ cat key.pub 
ssh-rsa MySRasKeytsadnasdnasd
$ sed -i 's!^!command="/sbin/shutdown -h now" !' key.pub
$ cat key.pub 
command="/sbin/shutdown -h now" ssh-rsa MySRasKeytsadnasdnasd
```